SPFx web parts missing in SharePoint 2019 modern sites
I'm trying to use an SPFx that contains some custom webparts on SharePoint 2019 (spfx-40-fantastics, you can find it in GitHub).
After deploying the SPFx everything works fine on classic sites, I can add webparts and everything works perfectly.
However, on a modern site, these webparts are not visible, I can't see them anywhere (obviously the app is added to site), when I click on the + button to add a webpart all I see is the built-in ones.
Anyone have any idea? I'm struggling with this situation for months.
Thanks in advance.

The installation states it's for Office online.
https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics/wiki/Installation-process
I am going to assume that maybe there is a difference in the SPFX version that is installed on your SP2019 farm vs what the package is targeting.
Maybe you are missing the name of the webpart you are trying to select.   Do you see the Bar chart web part on the modern pages?

Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don’t see the Bar chart webpart in modern pages. I didn’t understand what do you mean by difference between the spfx version the package is targeting, can you please explain to me more please

It does actually work in another 2019 environment. I have also tried using another custom spfx webpart built by a dev in my team but we are still having the same issue

SPFX version see reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility
SPFX in SP2019 is SPFX 1.4.1 and lower.    Then for each version of SPFX there are specific Node.JS, Typescript and React versions.      If things are working on one SP2019 farm vs another,   maybe there is a patching difference and JavaScript difference.

Thanks for your answer, are there actual patchs for javascript on SharePoint server?
